# Firebase Messaging - this browser doesnt not support firebase iphone issue

Tags: reactjs, firebase, progressive-web-apps

Messaging: This browser doesn't support the API's required to use the firebase SDK. (messaging/unsupported-browser)

I am getting this error in PWA app react. when i open app in iphone safari and chrome browser.

this works fine on android device. Expecting your speedy assistance on this.

I am using firebase below packages in my proejct-
1- "firebase": "^10.8.0",
2 - "@firebase/messaging": "^0.12.6",